# How do I write a Vertical Histogram using numbers?

Tags: histogram

Printing a vertical histogram. Write a program that asks the user to enter a list of integers and then prints a histogram vertically to the screen. The integers are entered as a string separated with spaces.

This is what my output is supposed to look like:

```
Please enter a string of integers separated by spaces: 1 3 6 5 2 7

******
 *****
 *** *
  ** *
  ** *
  *  *
     *
```

I can't figure out how to make the histogram vertical...help me?

Comment: What language are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The whole program should look like this:

```
read the numbers into a list.
print the histogram of the list.
```

To print the histogram of the list:

```
find the maximum of the numbers.
for each number starting with the maximum, going down to 1:
  print the corresponding line of the histogram.
```

To print line `x` of the histogram:

```
for each of the numbers from the list:
  if x is at least the number:
    print " *"
  otherwise:
    print "  "
print a linebreak
```

Now it's your task to convert this pseudo code into the language of your instructor's choice.

Answer (score 0):

vertical text histogram:

```
     |
  |  |
  || |
  || |
 ||| |
 |||||
||||||
```